# how to save turtlebot3 world and use nav2

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

when I run

```
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger && \
ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch.py
```

I can see a world with a robot.
but when I create a world with gazeboo (test.world) and save objects in this world and then run

```
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger && \
ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch.py world:=test.world
```

the world is not exporting.

I found a file turtlebot3_worlds/burger.model

```
<model name="turtlebot3_world">
<static>1</static>
<include>
    <uri>model://turtlebot3_world</uri>
</include>
</model>
```

and when I commend this part it removes the world, but I didn't find a way to launch tirtlebot3 and my world.
I get empty world if I comment that model.
But navigation doesn't work when I run
slam part

```
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger && \
ros2 launch turtlebot3_cartographer cartographer.launch.py use_sim_time:=True
```

and nav part

```
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger && \
ros2 launch turtlebot3_navigation2 navigation2.launch.py use_sim_time:=True map:=$HOME/map.yaml
```

Comment: If you want to load your own world, you have to create your own launch file. I couldn't find a launch file with a world parameter to load, unfortunately. Just copy the `turtlebot3_world.launch.py` file and [change the path to the world file here](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/blob/humble-devel/turtlebot3_gazebo/launch/turtlebot3_world.launch.py#L36-L40).

Comment: it's strange but I have a little different lines of code
I don't really have 'turtlebot3_world.world' but I will try it

    `world_file_name = 'turtlebot3_worlds/' + TURTLEBOT3_MODEL + '.model'
    world = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('turtlebot3_gazebo'),
                         'worlds', world_file_name)`

Comment: Checkout the branch for the ros distro you are using. I linked the version from ros2 humble.

Comment: I am using foxy. I cloned the repo changed turtlebot_3 world directly but it seems it loads the world from /opt/ros/foxy/share/turtlebot3_gazebo
and in the file path refers to a model world_file_name = 'turtlebot3_worlds/' + TURTLEBOT3_MODEL + '.model'
that I said above

Comment: is it possible to run turtlebot3_world.launch file in the repo and modify it?

Comment: If you used a cloned version of this repo directly you need to uninstall the binary version. The path to the world file is set with `get_package_share_directory('turtlebot3_gazebo')` which searches for the `turtlebot3_gazebo` package and it finds the binary one first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252620/discussion-between-darkproduct-and-le4a).